# Question with wrong author (or vice versa)

Tags: support

I came to Arqade from the link at the bottom Stack Overflow (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions)

I saw this:

[image]

However, when I look at the newest questions (https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions) I see this:

[image]

Obvious issue here is the names are not matching up.

Comment: That is not the author, it's the last change. (Well, except for some bugs) - In that case it's [James' edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/122447/revisions) that caused his name to appear there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is the latest person who *edited* the post, not the original author. This is part of the system that keeps people accountable for the edits that they make, all of which are public, and is working as intended.

Comment: The reason for the discrepancy is that you're looking at *Activity* in the first view versus *new questions* in the second.

Comment: Clears everything up, thanks for that.  Is this mentioned somewhere in FAQ (or whatever it is now)?